# Нужна помощь в wifi мониторинге

Tags: android, linux, mobile

Можно ли перевести xiaomi redmi 4 или zte blade a5 pro в режим wifi мониторинга?
Я пытался запустить мониторинг как написано здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/190554/ но когда я пишу в терминале iw выводит "error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported" что делать ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, для этого необходимо установить kali linux на телефон, но тут есть одно но. Вы попрощаетесь с гарантией телефона, так как нужен unroot для установки эмулятора. Вы сможете писать все видимые вами wifi в журнал, как и трафик.

Можно сделать и через терминал внутри android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=ru,

однако это опасней.Выглядит это так:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26486-Enable-monitor-mode-in-Kali-Linux-2

https://xakep.ru/2015/04/07/195-kalinethunter/

Comment: С чего бы это только Kali позволяет переводить модуль в режим мониторинга?

Comment: Через консоль, пожалуйста, переводите.

Comment: А дистрибутив тут при чем?

Comment: Софта предостаточно, кроме того вопрос состоял можно ли, и да можно, конкретный софт можно дописать.

Comment: Дистрибутив притом, что лучше не трогать ядро, если не хотите тратить много времени на восстановление потом.Я просто предложил один из вариантов решения. По моему телефон с мощным процессором может его поддержать. Если вы знаете альтернативы, велком.

Comment: Кроме того, человеку нужно мониторинг при помощи телефона https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26486-Enable-monitor-mode-in-Kali-Linux-2 и как я понял любыми средствами

Comment: Ядро и не надо трогать, есть модули. wireless-tools содержит iwconfig, который и будет переводить адаптер в нужный режим. И дистрибутив совсем не при чем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67570/discussion-between-vasilyuk-dmitry-and--).

Comment: А самое смешное, что на телефоне УЖЕ стоит линух и переставлять его не надо.